# How to auto checkout TFS file by other editor

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I opened a project by visual studio,and the project was controled by TFS.
When I edited any file by other editor like notepad,the will not auto checkout.

How to auto checkout the file when I edited in other editor?

Comment: @EdwardThomas - OP said `Notepad`, but in general `any` editor other than the build in VS editor.  but below answers are correct, you can only do this with an editor that is wedded to a TFS client, not an arbitrary editor like `Notepad`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) editor with [Sublime TFS](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Sublime%20TFS) plugin

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Auto checkout is a feature of visual studio.

However, If you upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 AND TFS 2012, you will be able to use a new feature named 'Local Workspaces' that will let you modify files without checking them out.  It will also recognize that you made the changes when you go to check in - so in effect it might be even better than having auto checkout!

Comment: Still valid as of TFS2015 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=vsts